# Laggy local html file .. common reasons?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I have problem with some of the local html file. I noticed that it only happens with long html files. I did a 1 minute video to show you the problem, please check it out.
https://youtu.be/WBeZpVErjuM

All html files are running through the same code. Do you guys know any common reason for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated it but since you were testing in an iOS simulator, I'm going to assume that you are using HTML5 to create a mobile app. When you do this it's best practice to have all your app pages in a single html file, as so called Single Page Application (SPA). This speeds things up as your assets files are only loaded once, rather than continuosly as you navigate to other pages in your app. More info: http://singlepageappbook.com/goal.html